# Verilog - Compile time calculations

Tags: parameters, system-verilog, synthesis

I need to do some calculations in compile time for a video driver. When the module is instantiated, WIDTH and HEIGHT parameters are defined. Then I compute some values from these.

```
parameter X_BLOCK = $floor(640 / WIDTH);
parameter Y_BLOCK = $floor(480 / HEIGHT);
parameter BLOCK = X_BLOCK < Y_BLOCK ? X_BLOCK : Y_BLOCK;
parameter X_SPAN = WIDTH * BLOCK;
parameter Y_SPAN = HEIGHT * BLOCK;
parameter X_START = $floor((640 - X_SPAN) / 2);
parameter Y_START = $floor((480 - Y_SPAN) / 2);
parameter X_STOP = X_START + X_SPAN;
parameter Y_STOP = Y_START + Y_SPAN;
```

These calculations should be performed at compile time, but I am getting errors that $floor is not synthesizable. I thought that parameters would be calculated at compile time, so why does it care if it can't synthesize $floor?

Comment: It might be a limitation with your synthesizer. An integer division typically rounds down if I remember correctly. You can also try `parameter X_BLOCK = int'(640 / WIDTH);` or `parameter int X_BLOCK = $floor(640 / WIDTH);` to get a `$floor` equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is `$floor` is a function that returns value with a `real` type. Since you did not explicitly provide data types for your parameters, they are implicitly defined with the type of the default initialization or the type of any expression they ore overridden with. So when you reference these parameters in expression within your design, they will become `real` expressions.

In SystemVerilog, it is always a good idea to provide an explicit data type for your parameters as @Greg suggests.

Comment: explicit datatypes do fix the problem